# Spring MVC Application - How do I set a session scoped bean value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

In my application I need to gather information on one screen and then display it on the next.

I have selected to store this information in a bean with a scope set as session ( it will be used in several other screens after the initial data gathering screen)

The Manager is configured as follows:

```
 <bean name="/springapp.htm" class="foo.bar.controller.springcontroller">
        <property name="sessionBeanManager" ref="sessionBeanManager" />
    </bean>
```

The bean is configured as follows :

```
<bean id="sessionBean" class="foo.bar.sessionBean" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
   <property name="beanValue" value="defaultValue" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionBeanManager" class="foo.bar.sessionBeanManagerImpl">
    <property name="sessionBean" ref="sessionBean"/>
</bean>
```

And I am outputting on the jsp page with

```
<c:out value="${sessionBean.beanValue}"></c:out>
```

but whenever I load the page the value is empty?

It seems to me that the bean is loading OK but is not populated with the value, which leads me to think that either the session bean is not being populated or the bean is not being created as a session bean?

Comment: how do you create the sessionBean?

Comment: There's no bean definition for `sessionBean` in your example - where is it?

Comment: Session bean now visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring beans are not visible in the views (JSPs in your case) unless you add them first to the model.

You have to add your sessionBean to the model in the controller to make it available to the view.

```
model.addAttribute("sessionBean", sessionBean);
```

Comment: How do I get access to the bean in the controller?

Comment: You have to inject it. Or get it through your sessionBeanManager already injected.

Comment: scoped proxies can be made visible.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3047273/366073

Answer (score 8):

You can reference spring session beans with the following syntax in your EL in the jsp.

```
${sessionScope['scopedTarget.messageUtil'].flashMessages}
```

That calls getFlashMessages() on this bean

```
<bean id="messageUtil" class="mypackage.MessageUtilImpl" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
    <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I posted a blog entry about it a couple weeks ago if you want more info.  http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/11/01/accessing-spring-session-beans-in-jsp/

Comment: I read that, and was able to get your method working.  However at first I had trouble because the spring container doesn't actually initialize the messageUtil until it is used.  How would you recommend pre-seeding messages so that they show up when someone first logs in?

Comment: Once they login, they have a good session, so you should be able to inject messageUtil into a controller or something and put messages in it.  The real difficulty is when they haven't logged in and you want to add messages like failed login or something.  We ended up handling that case a little differently.