# Spring MVC - JSP - Place to Store Environment Specific Constants

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Where in the Spring-MVC/JSP application would you store things that need to be accessed by both the controllers and views such as environment specific base_url's, application ids to be used in javascript and so on?

I've tried creating an application scoped bean and then `<jsp:useBean>` at the top of my JSPs, but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
   <!-- Environment -->
    <bean id="myEnv" class="com.myapp.MyAppEnvironment" scope="application">
        <property name="baseUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/myapp/"/>
        <property name="videoPlayerId" value="234346565"/>
    </bean>
```

And using it in the following manner

```
<jsp:useBean id="myEnv" scope="application" type="com.myapp.MyAppEnvironment"/>
```

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't seem to be working" more in developer's perspective than enduser's perspective. What exactly happens and what exactly not? Any error/exception (in the logs)?

Comment: It said that there isn't a bean of that scope found, it threw an exception, but I'm not even sure if this is how you're supposed to handle such a case, the type of the exception is : java.lang.InstantiationException: bean spEnv not found within scope

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is `scope="application"`? That's a new one to me.

Anyway, if all you need is for your JSPs to be able to access Spring beans, then you can expose the beans to JSTL using the `exposedContextBeanNames` property of `InternalResourceViewResolver`. For example:

```
<bean id="myEnv" class="com.myapp.MyAppEnvironment">
    <property name="baseUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/myapp/"/>
    <property name="videoPlayerId" value="234346565"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
      <list>
         <value>myEnv</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

and then in your JSP:

```
 ${myEnv.baseUrl}
```

Comment: scope="application" - http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html

That's an interesting feature of the view resolver, I'll try this and bump up the answer if it works for me, thanks