# get <aop:scoped-proxy/> that is session scoped inside of a jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have my user session stored as an `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` proxy. how would i go about accessing it on the jsp?

i am assuming that the bean is stored somewhere in the session, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: much the same question as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132928/spring-mvc-application-how-do-i-set-a-session-scoped-bean-value/4351255#4351255

Comment: very much eh? ill have to vote up that answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i found an answer:

http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/11/01/accessing-spring-session-beans-in-jsp/

in short:

```
${sessionScope['scopedTarget.userSession'].firstName}
```

works like a charm

Comment: Awesome, taught me something!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/stripes-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01337.html).  The issue is that session scoped beans (or beans in general) must be injected into the classes that need them and there isn't an easy way to do that with JSP pages.  In addition to the solution presented in the thread I linked, you could also inject the user session into your controllers and then add the object to your model.  Alternatively, if you wanted to switch to a framework like Spring Security for your user session management, you could make use of their [tag library](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) to access the user session information from a JSP.