# Spring MVC: HTTP session management "equivalent"

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, session-variables

I come from languages like PHP or ColdFusion: if I wanted to save something in user's http session I act like this:

```
SESSION["foo"] = "bar"
```

Now I am in a Spring MVC environment.

For example, inside a Controller method, how can I save a variable in session?

Someone told me that a *session-scoped bean* would get the job.

Can you help me with a trivial code snippet?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132928/spring-mvc-application-how-do-i-set-a-session-scoped-bean-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a session-scoped bean, and you may also have an argument of type HttpServletRequest or HttpSession on all your request handling methods. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-methods.

```
@RequestMapping...)
public String processSubmit(..., HttpSession session, ...) {
    ...
    session.setAttribute("someAttribute", someObject);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is the "quick and dirty" session (PHP old style like)

Comment: However... I'll set your answer as accepted, when you will edit it, including a simple example of using a session scoped bean

Comment: A session-scoped bean is used as any other injected bean. The way to configure and inject a session-scoped bean is described in the same documentation as the one I already linked to. Reading manuals and documentation is a very important part of a decent developer. You can't learn just by asking questions. Read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-scopes-session