# Changing from Struts 2.x to Spring 3x MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi  I am new to Spring MVC annotations . I am now on assignment of moving Stuts 2.x controller part to Spring annotation based , I am getting trouble while session.
I struts2 I used session aware , its store the map vales . In spring how can I achieve can any one please help me . ...
its more helpful for me if any one reply..with in week.
here is my struts 2.x action class .

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import com.cmt.admin.business.AdminService; 
import com.cmt.admin.dao.User; 
import com.cmt.common.constants.CommonConstants; 

public class LoginAction extends CMTAction { 
    private String userName; 
    private String profileName; 
    private String password; 
    private Map<String, String> securityData; 
    String pageName = CommonConstants.INDEX; 
    private String menuName; 

    @Autowired private AdminService cmtAdminService; 

    @Override 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    public String execute() throws Exception { 
        if((userName==null || (CommonConstants.EMPTY_STRING).equals(userName)) && (password==null || (CommonConstants.EMPTY_STRING).equals(password))) { 
            return CommonConstants.INVALID; 
        } 

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> securityData = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>(); 
        String returnStatus = CommonConstants.SUCCESS; 
        Map<String,Object> resultData = null; 
        Boolean validUser = false; 
        this.getSession().put(CommonConstants.MENU_NAME, CommonConstants.HOME); 
        resultData = cmtAdminService.loginProcess(userName, password,profileName); 
        validUser = (Boolean) resultData.get(CommonConstants.IS_VALID_USER); 
        if (validUser) { 
            User logggedUser = (User) resultData.get(CommonConstants.LOGGED_INUSER); 
            this.getSession().put(CommonConstants.LOGGED_INUSER, logggedUser); 
            securityData = (HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>) resultData.get( CommonConstants.SECURITY_DATA); 
            this.getSession().put(CommonConstants.SECURITY_DATA, securityData); 
            returnStatus = getPageSecurityData(pageName); return returnStatus; 
        } else { 
            showErrorMessage(CommonConstants.INVALID_USERNAME_PASSWRD_ERROR); 
            return CommonConstants.INVALID; 
        } 
    } 

    public String index() { 
        return CommonConstants.INDEX; 
    } 

    public String home() throws Exception { 
        if (this.getSession()==null || this.getSession().get(CommonConstants.LOGGED_INUSER) == null || "".equals(this.getSession().get(CommonConstants.LOGGED_INUSER))) { 
            return CommonConstants.INVALID; 
        } 
        String returnStatus = CommonConstants.SUCCESS; 
        returnStatus = getPageSecurityData(pageName); 
        return returnStatus; 
    } 

    private String getPageSecurityData(String pageName) throws Exception { 
        String returnStatus = CommonConstants.SUCCESS; 
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> securtyData = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>(); 
        Map<String, Object> resultData = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        Map<String, String> currentPageSecurty = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        securtyData = (HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>) this.getSession().get( CommonConstants.SECURITY_DATA); 
        resultData = cmtAdminService.getPageSecurityData(securtyData,pageName); 
        currentPageSecurty = (HashMap<String, String>) resultData .get(CommonConstants.CURRENT_PAG_SECRTY_INFO); 
        returnStatus = (String) resultData.get(CommonConstants.PAGE_ACTION); 
        setSecurityData(currentPageSecurty); 
        setMenuName((String) this.getSession().get(CommonConstants.MENU_NAME)); 
        return returnStatus; 
    } 

    public String getMenuName() { 
        return menuName; 
    } 
    public void setMenuName(String menuName) { 
        this.menuName = menuName; 
    } 
    public Map<String, String> getSecurityData() { 
        return securityData; 
    } 
    public void setSecurityData(Map<String, String> securityData) { 
        this.securityData = securityData; 
    } 
    public void setUsername(String value) { 
        this.userName = value; 
    } 
    public String getUsername() { 
        return userName; 
    } 
    public void setPassword(String password) { 
        this.password = password;             
    } 
    public String getPassword() { 
        return password; 
    }
    public String getProfileName() { 
        return profileName; 
    } 
    public void setProfileName(String profileName) { 
        this.profileName = profileName; 
    } 
}
```

This is my CMTAction class

```
    package com.cmt.admin.web.action;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.cmt.admin.dao.User;
import com.cmt.common.constants.CommonConstants;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CMTAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware
{

    // This Map will contain vales in Session
    private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;

    protected User getLoggedInUser()
    {

        User user = (User) this.getSession().get(CommonConstants.LOGGED_INUSER);
        return user;
    }

    protected void showActionMessage(String message)
    {
        addActionMessage(message);
    }

    protected void showErrorMessage(String message)
    {
        addActionError(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session)
    {
        this.sessionMap = session;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getSession()
    {
        return sessionMap;
    }


}
```

This is my struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="css_xhtml" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="resources.message,resources.label" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="sessionTimedOut"
                class="com.cmt.common.interceptors.SessionTimeOutInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="sessionCheck" class="com.cmt.common.interceptors.SessionCheckInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="CMTStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
                <interceptor-ref name="sessionTimedOut" />
                <interceptor-ref name="sessionCheck" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <default-interceptor-ref name="CMTStack"/>
        <default-action-ref name="index" />
        <global-results>
            <result name="index">/jsp/admin/pgLogin.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="sessionTimedOut">/jsp/admin/pgSessionTimedOut.jsp</result>
            <result name="invalid">/jsp/admin/pgLogin.jsp</result>
            <result name="uploadCodeComments">/jsp/iConfigure/pgUploadCode.jsp</result>


        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
                result="error" />
        </global-exception-mappings>

        <action name="index" method="index" class="LoginAction">
            <result name="index">/jsp/admin/pgLogin.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Login" method="execute" class="LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/jsp/admin/pgIndex.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Logout" method="logout" class="LogoutAction">
            <result name="success">/jsp/admin/pgLogin.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>       
        <action name="home" method="home" class="LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/jsp/admin/pgIndex.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="search" method="execute" class="SearchAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/iCRL/pgiCRL.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="icrl" method="search" class="SearchAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/iCRL/pgiCRL.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="searchCodes" method="searchCodes" class="SearchAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="json"></result>
        </action>
        <action name="searchicrl" method="submitPage" class="SearchAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="json"></result>
        </action>


        <action name="iconfdtl" method="retrieveIConfigureDetails" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/iConfigure/pgiConfigureReviewStep2.jsp
            </result>
        </action>
        <action name="retrieveCodeList" method="retrieveCodeList" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="json">
            </result>
        </action>

        <action name="filterassc" method="filterAssociationCodes" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="json">
            </result>
        </action>

        <action name="codeSearch" method="retrieveIConfigureDetails" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="invalid">/jsp/admin/pgSessionTimedOut.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/iConfigure/pgiConfigureReviewStep2.jsp
            </result>
        </action>

        <action name="iconfaddcategory" method="retrieveIConfigureViewDetails"
            class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/iConfigure/pgiConfigureCategory.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="iconfviewdtl" method="retrieveIConfigureViewDetails"
            class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>
        <action name="reloadconfdtl" method="retrieveIConfigureViewDetails"
            class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>

        <action name="populateaddnew" method="showAddNewForm" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>
        <action name="editaddnew" method="populateEditAssociationData" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>
        <action name="saverow" method="saveRowData" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/iConfigure/pgiConfigureReviewStep2.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="editassoc" method="saveEditedAddNewData" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>

    <action name="populateOrgUnit" method="populateOrgUnit" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>
     <action name="populateUserAccount" method="populateUserAccount" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result name="invalid">/jsp/admin/pgSessionTimedOut.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
    </action>

        <action name="addassoc" method="saveNewCodeAssociation" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>
        <action name="saveNewCategory" method="saveNewCategory" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>

        <action name="codeView" method="getCodeViewDetails" class="CodeViewAction">
            <result name="success">/jsp/iCRL/pgiCRLDetailView.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>
                <action name="iPolicyStepThreeSubmit" class="IPolicyAction" method="iPolicyList" >               
            <result name="success">/jsp/iPolicy/pgiPolicyDetailsStep4.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="iPolicyStepFourSubmit" class="IPolicyAction" method="iPolicyList" >                
            <result name="success">/jsp/iPolicy/pgiPolicy.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="findCategoryName" method="findCategoryName" class="IConfigureAction">
            <result name="error">/jsp/admin/pgError.jsp</result>
            <result type="json" name="success"></result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [SessionAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) annotation on my controller to have spring retaining in session some attributes that I will put in my model. Spring transparently put and retrieve from the session these attribute as they are put into the model or injected in a controller method. As the javadoc indicates, this is a good method when the attributes are to be set in session temporarily, and it advices another way to access the session directly for attributes that should stored permanently. This method is described with enough details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680529/spring-mvc-http-session-management-equivalent).

You should probably go for that.

Alternatively, for your security data for example, you could create a session-scoped bean in your application context of type java.util.HashMap and then inject it into your controller. I don't know if this is a good practice, but the advantage is you can inject this bean in services if needed.