# How do you store information in session memory in spring mvc to fetch later?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a unique situation in which I want to store an array of integers into memory via a POST.  I think want to fetch this data later with a GET request.

This may seem strange, and weird, but I do have a use case, and it will only be in memory for a few seconds.

A simple example  --  Store the array someArray = [1, 2, 3]; in some sort of in memory storage with a POST, and retrieve it via GET in another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will have access to `HttpServletRequest` in your controller, you just have to invoke [`getSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)) method:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

Now you have access to the Session, so you can store, retrieve and remove data from it using the relevant methods:

- [`HttpSession#setAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))
- [`HttpSession#getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))
- [`HttpSession#removeAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#removeAttribute(java.lang.String))

---

As said in comments, you can also omit getting the session manually and send it as parameter to your method from your `@Controller`. Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8682679/1065197)

```
@RequestMapping...)
public String processSubmit(..., HttpSession session, ...) {
    Object anAttribute = session.getAttribute("anAttribute");
}
```

Comment: in Spring controller that do not need to do this, just put the HttpSession as parameter of the method and directly use it.

Comment: thanks guys, I have actually just be informed that our cluster randomly wipes session memory, so I think I am going to have to rework the entire solution

Answer (score -1):

I ever had this kind of requirement that first posted main data to controller and then posted some detail data to controller and combine 2 kinds of data and retrieved data from database with these data. I just store the main data in session with `session.setAttribute()`, Spring mvc has a `@SessionAttribute`, but after tried dozens of time, I gave up, it's very difficlut to use.