# how to manage session attributes due to post requests, and history

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following problem:

I want to send information between modules (different controllers) using POST due to security reasons. My logic has been something like this:

User Searches > Clicks on specific item > Sends a form with post request to a controller > Controller shows view of the specific item > User clicks on a sub-item page > Sends a form with post request to the sub-item's controller

However, because of how POST works out, it's giving me "Webpage has expired" messages when going from Subitem page back to Item page.

My solution to this problem is to save these parameter(s) in Java's `HttpSession`, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650746/how-do-you-store-information-in-session-memory-in-spring-mvc-to-fetch-later). However I am not particularly sure how to go at it.

For example here is some snippets of my code (for the record I'm using thymeleaf as a view resolver):

**Search.html snippet**

```
<tr th:each="customer:${results.pageList}">
   <td>
       <form method="POST" id="goToUser" name="goToUser" action="/customer/">
           <input type="hidden" name="acctCustNbr" th:value="${customer.acctCustNbr}"/>
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('goToUser').submit();"
                th:text="${customer.acctCustNbr}">000010</a>
       </form>
   </td>
 <!-And so on-->
```

**Customer (or Item, in the example) controller that receives this request:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getCustomer(@RequestParam(value = "acctCustNbr", required = false) String acctCustNbr,
                          Model model,
                          HttpSession session) {
    boolean error = false;
    String errorMsg;
    logger.info("acctCustNbr obtained is >" + acctCustNbr + "<");
    if(acctCustNbr==null){
        acctCustNbr = (String) session.getAttribute("acctCustNbr");
    }
    else
        session.setAttribute("acctCustNbr", acctCustNbr);

    /*Service methods and model additions*/
```

Now how do I get past this initial stage? It seems my sub-item's controller can obtain the session attribute fine, but hitting back on the browser still opens up that dreaded expiration alert.

My logic is if a user is hitting the back button to this `/customer/` page that he will send `acctCustNbr==null`. Obviously I'm wrong because this doesn't work.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here?

---

---

**SOLUTION thanks to @skirsch**

I renamed my controller method to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCustomer(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    boolean error = false;
    String errorMsg;
    /** service invocations and stuff**/
```

And added this one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer1/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String storeAcctCustNbrInSession(@RequestParam(value = "acctCustNbr", required = false) String acctCustNbr,
                                        Model model, HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("acctCustNbr", acctCustNbr);
    return "redirect:/customer/";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the browser to another place after storing the data in the session. This other place could be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCustomerFromSessionValue(Model model, HttpSession session) { ... }
```

As you redirect using a GET method, you won't experience your "dreaded expiration alert".
See [*Redirect After Post*](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)

Comment: So should I just recreate the same POST method or could i invoke it inside this one? Sorry I know that's a stupid/beginner/rookie question but somehow I'm still confused.

Comment: nevermind, I got it. I'll edit to show what I did but will mark yours as an answer. Thank you!