# Doing PRG twice, how to get old attributes instead of newer ones on history back

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, post-redirect-get

I had a problem which required PRG to fix and was answered here:
[how to manage session attributes due to post requests, and history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888258/how-to-manage-session-attributes-due-to-post-requests-and-history/15889159?noredirect=1#15889159)

However, I seem to have another problem. Once the initial PRG happens, let's say I do the same PRG in order to show the user a *different* Customer. User views this new customer and upon hitting the back button it shows the previous page/customer just fine. My problem is that what is stored in session will be the **newest** customer id, and not the previous one.

I thought about making two more methods in my controller that mirror the first two I made for PRG, but that would require making more views in order for the user to not access any other session attribute dependent data/modules/views.

The only reason I'm using PRG and post requests is because I want to send all data securely and hidden.

Honestly I don't see how I can get around this, as I don't know any way of making a request on back button click. Should I abandon the PRG method? What should I use instead? Is there a way to make the PRG work, so that the back button behaves like in get requests?

Comment: With PRG you mean Post-Redirect-Get?

Comment: AFAIK Spring doesn't handle this (but maybe I'm wrong), but JSF does this by nature using `@ViewScoped` managed bean. Another approach you could do is to disable the caching in your site so the back button will generate a new request to your server.

Comment: Wouldn't that last one defeat the purpose of PRG? I implemented PRG so that on back it would not display the expiration alert.

Comment: I didn't mean to show an expire page when pressing the back button. I mean just to disable caching so when going back the browser will send a totally new request to the server.

Comment: I'm intrigued, would this be handled by Spring, my view resolver (thymeleaf) or straight up Tomcat?